# "Not even" as a conjunction or for contrast

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is this sentence fine?

It was pitch black, not even the stars could be seen.

I know that you can use a comma before not even and then a noun for contrast, but can it still work with a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Technically these are two sentences, so should be separated by a semicolon or perhaps a dash would do.

Grammatically this would then make sense. For me it's a bit jarring logically, as in my experience the less (artificial) light there is in spot, the more stars tend to be visible. This may not be what you're asking about, though.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I was unsure whether or not it needed to be two considered two independent clauses. As for the logic, I guess I was going with everything was so dark like if it was covered by fog or something, so even the stars couldn't be seen.

Comment: @Frazzles is right. It's two separate sentences, so putting a comma there creates a comma splice. You should use a semicolon or a period instead. As for "not even," you'd use a comma before "not even" in a sentence like this: "John invited none of his family to his wedding, not even his mom."